# What do the "GP 330.5" and "CH24X" I marked in the picture below mean?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, ils, phraseology, symbology, frequency

What do the "GP 330.5" and "CH24X" I marked in the picture below mean? I think 330.5 is localizer independent glidepath frequency but I have no idea what CH24X means. Does anyone know the details of every letter?

The image is from AIP TURKEY AD 2 LTAF ADC chart.

[image]

Comment: Seems like they ought to be frequencies for the ILS, but different than US frequencies for navaids.

Comment: Important part is CH24X for me now.

Comment: Does your ILS receiver use channels within that range?

Comment: 24X might be a TACAN channel... those are one- to three-digit numbers plus an "X" or "Y" so it would fit, and it's believable a DME transmitter would be colocated with an ILS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I understand it, the ILS device provides the Localizer (LOC) and Glidepath (GP) frequencies to pair on a 24X coded TACAN frequency channel. Is what we call 24X here exactly a frequency that acts as a pairing device in the ILS device? @RTO

Comment: The point that I find strange here is that there is a frequency range given as 24X, so I wanted to be sure.

Comment: This link would be helpful for you: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/82204/why-do-ifr-charts-show-tacan-paired-frequencies-when-there-is-no-collocated-vor

Answer (score 12, accepted):

24X is the paired TACAN channel. It's paired (permanently associated) with 108.7 MHz (localizer frequency for LTAF) and 330.5 MHz (Glide Slope). See this [reference](https://wiki.radioreference.com/index.php/Instrument_Landing_System_(ILS)_Frequencies). (Scroll down to see the table)

So, if I tune in the localizer frequency (108.7 MHz at LTAF) my ILS navigation equipment would automatically also tune in 330.50 MHz (the Glide Slope frequency) and, if my nav equipment also included a DME unit, I would see my distance from the DME facility, which looks like it is at the same location as the Glide Slope antenna at LTAF.  If, for some reason, I did not have a separate DME unit in the aircraft, but had a separate TACAN nav unit, I could set the TACAN channel to 24X (which tunes in the DME interrogation frequency of 1048 MHz and a reply frequency of 985 MHZ) and would be able to access the DME through the TACAN unit.

There is only azimuth guidance (in addition to distance/DME info) from a TACAN unit when navigating to/from a VORTAC or TACAN station, which is not at issue in your question.

I've merged the column headings in the image below with the reference for Channel 24X.

[image]